# MySQL - синхронизация данных в таблицах

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы БД MySQL - Result и Source.

```
Result
+------+------+-----+
|  id  | text | num |
+------+------+-----+
| 1234 | aaaa |  0  |
+------+------+-----+
| 2345 | bbbb |  2  |
+------+------+-----+
| 3456 | cccc |  1  |
+------+------+-----+

Source
+------+------+
|  id  | text |
+------+------+
| 3456 | cccc |    
+------+------+
| 1234 | eeee |
+------+------+
| 4567 | dddd |
+------+------+
```

Можно-ли запросом MySQL синхронизировать по id записи из Source в Result таким образом, чтоб в Result были все те же записи из Source, только:

```
в таблице Result:
1. Записи у которых id совпали - сохранили свое значение num
2. Записи у которых id совпали, а text нет - обновили свое значение text из Source, 
   а значение num записать 0.
3. Удалить записи из Result, id которых нет в Source
4. Добавить записи из Source, id которых нет в Result. 
   num = 0 поставится автоматически.
```

Результат выполнения:

```
Result
+------+------+-----+
|  id  | text | num |
+------+------+-----+
| 3456 | cccc |  1  |
+------+------+-----+
| 1234 | eeee |  0  |
+------+------+-----+
| 4567 | dddd |  0  |
+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: п. 1, 2, 4 делаются с помощью `insert into result ... on duplicate key update ... select ... from source`. п. 3 отдельным запросом `delete .. where not exists ...` (или delete ... left join)

Comment: у меня проблема с `DELETE m FROM baseTest.Result m LEFT JOIN baseTest.Source r ON r.id = m.id WHERE r.id IS NULL;`

Comment: `No database selected` - но я же везде указал baseTest.*

Comment: сделайте просто `use baseTest` первой командой. а так запрос нормальный

Comment: @Mike так я делаю. Мне б добиться, чтоб без этого use baseTest... Чего ему не хватает в запросе, не знаете?

Comment: Не знаю, чисто по синтаксису ему всего должно хватать. Другие БД наверняка бы спокойно все выполнили. Но MySQL довольно загадочный, что ему когда нужно